# Required value in regex

Tags: regex

At the moment I have:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$
```

I want `blah/blah` to match, but I don't want `c/blah` or `/blah` or `blah/` or `blah/c`to match (So I want it to have at least two values either side of the string.

Just a note, the `^` and `$` are because the whole string much match the regex, not just part of it.

Comment: So it must be the same value on both sides? Or at least two characters?

Comment: Oops, I didn't make that clear. As long as it has two+ characters either side of the / then its fine. It doesn't have to be the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the expression as follows:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]{2,}/[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]{2,}$
```

Using `{2,}` in place of `*` ensures *at least* two matches of the prior regexp must be made.

Comment: +1 In Perl I found I had to escape the forward slash in the middle: ^[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]{2,}`\/`[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]{2,}$